# Search and replace in multiple files based on condition

Tags: text-processing

I am porting a Visual Studio C++ project to Linux, and would like to find all lines in all .h and .cpp files that start with #include and in any of those lines would like to replace the backslash with the forward slash.

There are a few scripts on how to do a search and replace online (using perl or sed for example), but none with a condition.

What's the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sed, you can put a regexp (between `/…/`) before the `s` command to only perform the replacement on lines containing that regexp. The `-i` option to modify files in place is specific to GNU sed (which is what you have on Linux and Cygwin).

```
sed -i -e '/^ *# *include/ s!\\\\!/!g' **/*.h **/*.cpp
```

In Perl, just put a conditional before doing the replacement.

```
perl -i -pe 'if (/^\s*#\s*include/) {s!\\\\!/!g}' **/*.h **/*.cpp
perl -i -pe '/^\s*#\s*include/ and s!\\\\!/!g' **/*.h **/*.cpp
```

The `**/` syntax to match files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively requires zsh, or bash ≥4 after doing `shopt -s globstar`. With other shells, you need to use find.

```
find \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec perl -i -pe '…' {} +
```