# Search and replace text within multiple files

Tags: text-processing

I am migrating my blog, and all the posts have metadata at the top of the file. As a result I have a group of nearly 100 files in a directory where I want to do a search and replace for:

```
^permalink: http://blog.olddomain.com/(.*)$
```

to

```
permalink: http://blog.newdomain.com/$1
```

in all 100 files.

What commands would I use to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search and replace in multiple files based on condition](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14092/search-and-replace-in-multiple-files-based-on-condition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` is often used to pipe something through it, but it can process files just as well and, with the `-i` option, can even change them in place.

```
sed -i 's|^\(permalink: http://blog\.\)olddomain\(\.com/.*\)$|\1newdomain\2|g' <shell-glob-pattern>
```